# ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve 5 equations with 5 unknowns.

```py
from sympy import *

w1, w2, w3, h2, h3 = symbols('w1 w2 w3 h2 h3')

tan = 8.89/19
h1 = 17.73
wt = 19

a1 = h1*w1+(w1*w1*tan)/2
a2 = h2*w2+(w2*w2*tan)/2
a3 = h3*w3+(w3*w3*tan)/2
a4 = w2*(h1+w1*tan-h2)+w3*(h1+(w1+w2)*tan-h3)
at = (h1*wt)+(wt*wt*tan)/2

eq1 = a1 - a2
eq2 = a1 - a3
eq3 = a1 - a4
eq4 = a1+a2+a3+a4-at
eq5 = w1+w2+w3-wt

answer = nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5), (w1, w2, w3, h2, h3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
print(answer)
```

But I receive an error:

> ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular

More call stacks:

```
File "/home/m3/Downloads/map/v-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/optimization.py", line 660, in __iter__
    s = self.ctx.lu_solve(Jx, fxn)
  File "/home/m3/Downloads/map/v-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/matrices/linalg.py", line 226, in lu_solve
    A, p = ctx.LU_decomp(A)
  File "/home/m3/Downloads/map/v-env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/mpmath/matrices/linalg.py", line 136, in LU_decomp
    raise ZeroDivisionError('matrix is numerically singular')
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my equations. The equations are for a geometry. The equations are trying to divide a geometric area into 4 equal areas. Can anybody provide some hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58325906/3405291), the error got resolved by adding:

```py
eq1 = nsimplify(eq1, rational=1)
eq2 = nsimplify(eq2, rational=1)
eq3 = nsimplify(eq3, rational=1)
eq4 = nsimplify(eq4, rational=1)
eq5 = nsimplify(eq5, rational=1)
```

Then, calling `nsolve` with different starting values:

```py
answer = nsolve((eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5), (w1, w2, w3, h2, h3), (6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

But another message is received:

> ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance.
> (5846.21208448752672242 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19)
>
> Try another starting point or tweak arguments.